# export parameterized variables in shellscript using sshpass

Tags: shell, variables, parameterized, sshpass

I have a use case similar to the below code. Need to export parameterized variables/identifier to remote shell script from a shell script. I used the below code but I cannot export the value. Please suggest how to do it.

#### A.sh (script 1)

```
#!/bin/bash
sshpass -p asdf ssh rock@host.com<<'ENDSSH'
export directory="$1"
sh /../B.sh
ENDSSH
```

#### B.sh (script 2)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo directory=$directory
mkdir $directory

#Execution
sh A.sh '/data/2017-7-7/' 

#output
directory=
```

I get the value in the remote shell script when I hard code the value.

```
export directory='/data/2017-7-7/'
```

I want to export parameterized variable, please suggest how to implement this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove quotes from the first `ENDSSH`:

```
sshpass -p asdf ssh rock@host.com << ENDSSH
export directory="$1"
sh /../B.sh
ENDSSH
```

---

According to the bash manual:

> **Here Documents**
>
> [...]
>
> The format of here-documents is:
>
> ```
> [n]<<[-]word
>     here-document
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No  parameter  and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic
>   expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on *word*.  **If any part  of
>   *word*  is  quoted, the *delimiter* is the result of quote removal on *word*,
>   and the lines in the  here-document  are  not  expanded.**   If  *word*  is
>   unquoted,  all  lines  of  the here-document are subjected to parameter
>   expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the  character
>   sequence  `\<newline>`  is  ignored, and `\` must be used to quote the
>   characters `\`, `$`, and `` ` ``.
>
> [...]